# For what values of the parameter $c$ the difference equation have periodic (2-cycle) solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have difference equation:
$y(n+1)=y(n)^2+c$

At what value of parametr $c$ the equation have a 2-cycle solution?

In this example $f(y)=y^2+c$

To solve the problem, I wanted to solve this equation: $y=f(f(y))$ because solution of the equation is periodic 2-cycle.

i got the roots of this equation:

$y_1=\frac{1}2(-\sqrt{-4c-3}-1)$

$y_2=\frac{1}2(\sqrt{-4c-3}-1)$

$y_3=\frac{1}2(-\sqrt{1-4c}+1)$

$y_4=\frac{1}2(\sqrt{1-4c}+1)$

but I don't know what to do next. How to find the necessary parameter values using the roots?

Comment: This is a **difference** equation not a differential equation.

Comment: thank you, i fixed.